# Problem with wait by attribute in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

### ----- Update 5 days later
Finally, I found a solution. Does this fix the problem, I don't know. What was the source of the problem? I don't know. But at least it works!
In terms of wait times per attribute, I was querying the data from the journey. I changed that by querying the contact data and adding the ED used in the data designer.

I searched the site and did not see a similar case so I post my case.
I created a journey with several branches, on one of them, I encountered a problem with a wait by attribute. +4000 contacts left the journey during this wait time.

screen below

[image]

The data is correctly filled in the data extension. We query the data extension of the journey and it has not been modified. There are no exit criteria in the journey.

This behavior I have also in another journey. Same settings. Except that the data extension is different.

I noticed that the message activity following the wait by attribute in each journey is an SMS. This is the only common point between the two journeys.

So I did a test with one journey. I created a journey with one of the 2 data extensions used and created two wait by attributes, one without SMS activity behind it, and one with SMS activity behind it. Here is the result.

[image]

It's clean.

Does anyone have an idea? Also I contacted Salesforce support.

Comment: After two days of searching, i'm still having found the problem :-(

Comment: Finally, I found a solution. Does this fix the problem, I don't know. What was the source of the problem? I don't know. But at least it works! 
In terms of wait times per attribute, I was querying the data from the journey. I changed that by querying the contact data and adding the DE used in the data designer.